# Concatenate two columns values and create consecutive unique ID based on specific column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset, df, where I would like to merge two column values into one and then add a consecutive numeric value at the end based on a specific column.

Data

```
id  date
aa  q122
aa  q122
aa  q122
aa  q222
bb  q122
bb  q122
aa  q222
bb  q222
cc  q122
cc  q222
```

Desired

```
id  date    type
aa  q122    aa_q122_1
aa  q122    aa_q122_2
aa  q122    aa_q122_3
aa  q222    aa_q222_1
bb  q122    bb_q122_1
bb  q122    bb_q122_2
aa  q222    aa_q222_2
bb  q222    bb_q222_1
cc  q122    cc_q122_1
cc  q222    cc_q222_1
```

Doing

The consecutive numbers on the end of the values reset back to 1 when there is a new date value.
ex.

```
aa   q122   will become aa_q122_1,

however, once the date changes from q122 to q222, now the count aa_q122_1



df["type"] = df["id"] + df["date"]
```

but not sure how to add consecutive values at the end. I am researching this now. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try via `groupby()` and `cumcount()`:

```
df['type']=df['id']+'_'+df['date']+'_'+(df.groupby(['id','date']).cumcount()+1).astype(str)
```

output of `df`:

```
    id  date    type
0   aa  q122    aa_q122_1
1   aa  q122    aa_q122_2
2   aa  q122    aa_q122_3
3   aa  q222    aa_q222_1
4   bb  q122    bb_q122_1
5   bb  q122    bb_q122_2
6   aa  q222    aa_q222_2
7   bb  q222    bb_q222_1
8   cc  q122    cc_q122_1
9   cc  q222    cc_q222_1
```